# Swagger Recursively resolving dependencies for type (Infinite loop)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

We wanted to use Swagger for an existing Spring-boot project ( > 70 model, > 250 endpoint) and we run into an issue where the application does not start and it enters in an infinite loop while setting up Swagger.

- Log

```
...
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.500 Recursively resolving dependencies for type X;
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.500 Adding type X2; for parameter x2
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Recursively resolving dependencies for type X2;
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Adding type Ljava/util/List<X3>; for parameter x3s
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Adding collectionElement type X3;
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type X3;
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Adding type Ljava/util/List<X4;>; for parameter x4s
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Adding collectionElement type X4;
[DEBUG] 2020-01-04 23:28:32.501 Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type X4;
...
```

- POM

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        ....
    <dependencies>
```

Any help appreciated, even some hints of how to dig into this problem, because the log is not helpful and I do not know where to start!
Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Had (Have) the same problem, the workaround we ended up using ids instead of whole objects thanks to spring magic. Just adding `@ApiIgnore` for params which caused problems and then manually add `ApiImplicitParam` like

```
@ApiImplicitParam(
    required = true,
    value = "XxxId, of provided Xxx. Not Required",
    paramType = "query",
    dataType = "int"
)
@GetMapping(value = ["/XXX_PATH"])
fun getYyy(
    @ApiIgnore @RequestParam(required = false, value = Xxx_ID) xxx: Xxx?
): List<Yyy>
```

I guess if you really need to have whole objects in docs and not just Ids of them you would need to read docs on `dataType`. Good luck.

Comment: As I understand, so I should go through all my api endpoint that have this problem (using object instead of ids) and make this changes, right? also something, is that how do I could figure out which end points have this problem because the log is not very helpful (I have > 250 endpoints!), thank you very much.

Comment: I won't say this will be easy, maybe there is even better way. In our case we had swgger from begging so we noticed that one change broke it and it was pretty quick to fix. As general approach: understand your domain and check where are cycles in object you expose in API. DB auto generated diagrams can be helpful if you have high resemblance of db entities to REST resources which is true for most apps. As other method try commenting out whole Controllers / delete packages and use bisection to find problematic ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore problem specific classes globally.

`docket.ignoredParameterTypes(Order.class)`

https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#q18